# Passing BOOL between View Controllers in iOS Application | Passing Objects to View Controllers in iOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean

I´m trying to pass a BOOL value forward to a view controller (GameViewController) from another view controller (OptionsViewController), but nothing happens.

I created a property for the BOOL in in GameViewViewController.h

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isMusicEnabled;
```

and I told OptionsViewController about the GameViewController

```
#import "GameViewController.h"
```

and then pressing a button once would then set isMusicEnabled in GameViewController to BOOL value YES and pressing it again would set isMusicEnabled to NO;

But it doesn´t seem like

```
//GameViewController
if(isMusicEnabled == YES){
      NSLog(@"isMusicEnabled == YES");
}
if(isMusicEnabled == NO){
      NSLog(@"isMusicEnabled == NO");
}
```

is being accessed.

```
//OptionsViewController
- (void) MusicRingPushed:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"MusicRingPushed:(id)sender.");
     //GameViewController *gameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil];
     GameViewController *gameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil];

     if(_MusicON == YES){
         [_MusicRing setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ring2hd.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [self.view addSubview:_MusicRing];
         _MusicON = NO;
         NSLog(@"_MusicON ==YES");
         gameViewController.isMusicEnabled = NO;
         //[self pushViewController:gameViewController animated:YES]; //doesn´t work
     }
     else if (_MusicON == NO){
         [_MusicRing setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ring1hd.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [self.view addSubview:_MusicRing];
         _MusicON = YES;
         NSLog(@"_MusicON == NO");
         gameViewController.isMusicEnabled = YES;
         //[self pushViewController:gameViewController animated:YES]; //doesn´t work
         }
}

//GameViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    self.scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    self.scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Load the level.
    self.level = [[Level alloc] init];
    self.scene.level = self.level;

    //creates the block and assigns it to GameScene’s swipeHandler property.
    /*id block = ^(Swap *swap) {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        if ([self.level isPossibleSwap:swap]) {
            NSLog(@"*** [self.level isPossibleSwap:swap];");
            [self.level performSwap:swap];
            [self.scene animateSwap:swap completion:^{
                //self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                [self handleMatches];
            }];
         } else {
                self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
           }
        };

        self.scene.swipeHandler = block;*/

        id block = ^(Swap *swap) {
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            NSLog(@"id block = ^(Swap *swap)");
            [self.level performSwap:swap];
            [self.scene animateSwap:swap completion:^{
                NSLog(@"[self.scene animateSwap:swap completion:");
                [self handleMatches];
                self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            }];
        };

        self.scene.swipeHandler = block;

        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:self.scene];

        //loads the background music MP3 and sets it to loop forever
        NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Mining by Moonlight" withExtension:@"mp3"];
        self.backgroundMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
        self.backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1;
        [self.backgroundMusic play];

        if(isMusicEnabled == YES){
            NSLog(@"isMusicEnabled == YES");
        }
        if(isMusicEnabled == NO){
            NSLog(@"isMusicEnabled == NO");
        }
        if(isSFXEnabled == YES){
            NSLog(@"isSFXEnabled == YES");
        }
        if(isSFXEnabled == NO){
            NSLog(@"isSFXEnabled == NO");
        }
        // Let's start the game!
        [self beginGame];
}
```

I´ve tried with a segue and then it works fine, as long as I use an identifier and push a view, but this time I just want to pass a BOOL value without pushing the view.

Comment: There is no moving code from `OptionsViewController` to `GameViewController`, you never push that gameViewController instance.

Comment: check this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/4831524

Comment: @AntonyRaphel - already read that article, it did´t work. :(

Answer (score 0):

To get the updated value of a variable in your previous view controller then one solution you can try is use `NSUserDefaults`. Using this you can set initial value in your **firstViewController**. And after some action performed in your **secondViewController** update the `NSUserDefaults` variable with the new value.